# Will my worlds be preserved if I delete Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I reset my phone and I forgot about my Minecraft world until now.

Will I lose it for good or will it still be there after I log in to my Minecraft account?

Answer (score 1):

If you deleted the app from your device, there's a chance that the data of the minecraft world has been saved, and you'd just need to re-install.

If you fully reset your device, the world is gone - it isn't saved to the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Don't delete the game on Android (can't speak for any other system) unless you first back up your world saves. THEY WILL BE DELETED! I made this mistake when I switched back to community version, from the beta version, because I could no longer join my son's games. Switching to beta version only requires a update. Switching back to community version requires a delete and reinstall. Google failed me, when the top answers said I wouldn't lose my world's, or mods. Mods aren't an issue, just reinstall. World's being deleted was a kick in the mouth. Good idea to backup your saves before uninstall, regardless of the system your playing on.